# How do I get a URL structure with useful information in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I've got a website which has a URL structure that is not at all useful for breadcrumbs, conducive to SEO, or intuitive for users.  It's something like

`asdf.com/directory/listing/{unique_id}/{unique-page-name}/`

I would really like to change this to

`asdf.com/{state}/{city}/{unique_id}/{unique-page-name}/`

or something very similar.  This way, I can implement breadcrumbs in the form of

`Home > State > City > Company`

Does anyone have any ideas as far as converting the current structure to one as I've described above?  Any way I look at it, it seems that it'll require a complete overhaul of the website.  It would just be great to be able to show users something like `Home > Florida > Miami > Bob's Haircuts`

Thanks!

Comment: learn about routes, that is what will solve it. look in the userguide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just need to be creative with your routes: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

You can set up a route to catch all traffic and point it to `directory/listing`, then in your `listing` method - you can access the url segments manually. For example:

```
// application/config/routes.php
$route[':any'] = "directory/listing";
    /**
     you might have to play with this a bit, 
     I'm not sure, but you might need to do something like:
       $route[':any'] = "directory/listing";
       $route[':any/:any'] = "directory/listing";
       $route[':any/:any/:any'] = "directory/listing";
       $route[':any/:any/:any/:any'] = "directory/listing";
    */

// application/controllers/directory.php

function listing()
{
    // docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html
    $state = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $city = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $unique_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $unique_page_name = $this->uri->segment(4);

    // then use these as needed

}
```

OR, as is probably the case, you need to be able to call other controllers and methods -

You can change the URL to point to a controller, then do the listing stuff -

So your url would become:

```
asdf.com/directory/{state}/{city}/{unique_id}/{unique-page-name}/
```

and your route would become:

```
 $route['directory/:any'] = "directory/listing";
```

Then, you'd need to update the uri segments in your `listing` method to match the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th segments.

This way, you could still call another controller and it wouldn't be caught by your custom route:

```
asdf.com/contact/  --> would still access the contact controller and index method
```

**UPDATE**

You could also get creative and use a regular expression to catch any urls with state names in the first uri segment - then push those to `directory/listing` and then all other controllers will still work and you don't have to add the `directory` controller in the url. Something like this might work:

```
// application/config/routes.php
$route['REGEX-OF-STATE-NAMES'] = "directory/listing";
$route['REGEX-OF-STATE-NAMES/:any'] = "directory/listing"; // if needed
$route['REGEX-OF-STATE-NAMES/:any/:any'] = "directory/listing"; // if needed
$route['REGEX-OF-STATE-NAMES/:any/:any/:any'] = "directory/listing"; // if needed


/**
REGEX-OF-STATE-NAMES -- here's one of state abbreviations:
    http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=471
*/
```

Comment: This solution ended up working perfectly.  Thanks so much for the effort!  :D